# Get XPath for element

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to use selenium and I couldn't get the XPath of an element although I inspected the element and copy the XPath
This is the URL of the website
https://www.moj.gov.kw/AR/pages/eservices01.aspx
The element is the square next to "I'm not a robot" and this is my try that didn't work

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']").Click
```

Comment: I don't see such element on the site. But you have the `id` of the element. Why dont you use `FindElementByID("recaptcha-anchor")`?

Comment: I tried using ByID but the same problem. I got an error No Such element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have tested this and it works :

import this classes first:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

this code will click the button

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'a-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-border']"))).click();
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot. When using selenium the captcha apears with some images to click and review while when using google chrome in the normal state, this doesn't happen and the check mark is ok without any images. Any idea?

Comment: Actually now you are trying to pass recaptcha with a bot which is something goes to another question . Plz hit the checkmark in my answer to tell that it is answered and you can do additional research for the captcha control. You asked how to click the button and I answered ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you guide me with a link?

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked inside the DOM if this captcha is inside an iframe?
If so you'll need to switch to this frame first.